# Easy-to-apply tests for randomness

Tags: r, randomness

I'm interested in testing a sequence of numbers for randomness. I've done some searching and come across [die hard](http://www.stat.fsu.edu/pub/diehard/) and [die harder](http://www.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/General/dieharder.php). However these tests seem to require some expertise to apply, or at least aren't as well documented or easy to use as R, say. Also die harder require a *nix platform.

I'm working on windows platform, and although it would be possible to generate a csv file at work and send it home where I could process the file on linux using die harder, that would be a pain, and likely a lot of work. So I've looked at what's available in R, and come up with the [lawstat package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lawstat/index.html), which implements `bartels.test` and `runs.test`. It was pretty straightforward to get those tests going on my data.

I'm wondering, are there other tests that I could reasonably be running that wouldn't require much time, or should I just leave it there? There's no reason to suspect that the number I'm seeing aren't reasonably random: the main focus of the testing I need to do is to look at whether several vectors of random numbers are correlated according to some parameters that have been set up. So I'm looking at measures of correlation between sequences, but I also also want to test that each sequence is random, just to be sure that the process of introducing correlations hasn't introduced some problem in the marginal distributions.

What I suspect is that there might be a 90/10 rule here -- the final 10% of applying all the tests, in die hard, say, might be a disproportionate amount of effort, and if I can get 90% of the way there in R or similar, that would be good.

Comment: DieHard [runs on Windows](http://www.stat.fsu.edu/pub/diehard/).  [I applied it](http://www.quantdec.com/arcview.htm) *using Excel* over 14 years ago.

Comment: @whuber thanks, you're right, die hard does run on Windows (I looked at both of these last week and should have double checked before posting). I've amended my question accordingly. In your opinion, is die hard easy enough to run for someone who's relatively inexperienced? (I've added another sentence to the end of my question to clarify.)

Comment: If you're looking at correlation within and between series a first test to consider would probably be to look at ACF/PACF (within) and the CCF (between)

Comment: @Glen_b thanks, ACF/PACF would certainly be a good idea. The point of these sequences is that there _should_ be correlations between them (for which I'll use Spearman and then Kendall), but if one of the sequences is shifted these correlations should disappear, so CCF could work also.

Comment: The DieHard test requires almost no statistical experience to apply: it is fully automatic. It does require a little bit of *computing* experience, because it needs an 11 MB file containing a long binary sequence of 31 or 32 bit values from your random number generator. The documentation is clear and even the source code is available (in several languages) if you have any questions.

Comment: @whuber Thanks I'm ok at computing, but what you wrote reminds me of another thing that I saw that I didn't like, namely that it wants 32 bit _integers_, but my rng generates floating point (double precision) numbers from `Z=N(0,1)`. Will die hard test those? This page, http://www.johnmyleswhite.com/notebook/2012/10/15/the-shape-of-floating-point-random-numbers, indicates that die hard is suitable to "test uniform random numbers over unsigned integers". I couldn't find any documentation to show how to use die hard for floats. Perhaps I could use the cdf to transform to an integer?